Is "work routine" the correct term for a strictly defined work process?
The place I'm currently consulting at has defined a strict set of workflows to follow when different types of incidents happen.
To me, "workflows" are more guides that have been created to help the employees and may or may not be used.
The client's work processes have been suggested, peer-reviewed, and approved. They cannot be used otherwise.
Google translate suggested "Work routine", is that a strict enough definition?
Edit:
I asked ChatGPT and got the following answer:

It sounds like you're describing a standard operating procedure (SOP). SOPs are detailed instructions that outline the steps to be followed in various situations to accomplish specific tasks or handle incidents effectively. They're typically developed, reviewed, and approved by subject matter experts or relevant authorities to ensure consistency and safety in operations.

I'm going with that.

I see nothing wrong with "workflow". There's nothing in the term that implies that it's just a suggestion.

"work routine" is just a common progression of steps at work, not a specified recipe for a particular incident.

@Barmar Nothing implies that "Workflow" must be followed either. I'm looking for a term that does that.

"procedure" is another common term. You might try asking on [workplace.se].

It’s arguably the same thing, but flowchart sounds more rigid than workflow.

Response plan, reaction plan, EAP (Emergency Action Plan; OSHA term), etc. It depends.

Workflow is fine, but perhaps more detail is needed on the nature of the operations. Are they processes for day-to-day operation (which in business are called business processes, but in manufacturing, extraction, or agriculture will have other names)? Or are they procedures for emergencies or rarely-occurring situations? Are they instructions for how to use machinery e.g. shutdown procedures? Do they cover large parts of the business for long periods of time? Do they relate to a specific side of the business like HR?

There exists one step-by-step procedure that must be followed for each type of incident.

With routine, I meant a sequence of actions and nothing else.

Incidents are not 'routine' but quite the opposite: they disrupt the routine, and the workflow. A strictly defined response is a procedure. Cambridge Dictionary has

workflow the way that a particular type of work is organized, or the order of the stages in a particular work process:
The right software tools can improve workflow and productivity.

and

procedure a set of actions that is the official or accepted way of doing something:
The company has new procedures for dealing with complaints.

So an emergeny response to an incident isn't 'workflow' but a 'procedure'.

I think they're using the noun sense of "routine", as in a "dance routine", not the adjective that means "ordinary".

@Barmar I did write "they disrupt the routine".

But you also said "are not 'routine'". In any case, the discussion isn't about what's going on around this, but what you do to resolve the incident. So there can be a routine that's used when an indident disrupts the routine operation.
